# What does と do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> 怪物を退治し、人々を救い、囚われの姫様を助け出す、最高に格好良い英雄達のように自分もなりたい**と**、当時の僕は本気でそんな夢を抱いていた。

Could someone explain to me what the と does at the end of the sentence? Is it used as a quoting particle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 怪物を退治し、人々を救い、囚われの姫様を助け出す、最高に格好良い英雄達のように自分もなりたい**と**、当時の僕は本気でそんな夢を抱いていた。

**＝**

> 『怪物を退治し、人々を救い、囚われの姫様を助け出す、最高に格好良い英雄達のように自分もなりたい。』**と**、当時の僕は本気でそんな夢を抱いていた。

This 「と」 is the quotative particle.  The inside of the 『　』 is what the speaker seriously thought to himself back then.  It is what 「そんな夢」 refers to as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following chain of sentences.

> 自分もなりたいと思った。
>   自分もなりたいと、僕は思った。
>   自分もなりたいと、当時の僕は思った。
>   自分もなりたいと、当時の僕は本気で思った。
>   自分もなりたいと、当時の僕は本気でそんな夢を抱いていた。

Now consider it in reverse order. Are you still in doubt as to whether と here is the quoting particle?